# How to apply some changes to each element in List<List<>> structure using Java 8 approach

Tags: java, list, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have some structure like  `List<List<Double>> listOfDoubles` I need to transform it to `List<List<Integer>> listOfInteger`. I wrote code without using Java 8. And it looks like:

```
List<List<Integer>> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < doubleList.size(); i++) {
    for (Double doubleValue : doubleList.get(i)) {
        integerList.get(i).add(doubleValue.intValue());
    }
}
```

I tried to replace second `for` by `foreach` but can't because `i` should be final. How to write this code using Java 8 approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could stream the "outer" list, generating a `Stream<List<Double>`. Then, stream each of the "inner" lists, convert each element to an `Integer` and collect the result. Then just collect the "outer" stream. If you bring it all together, you'd get something like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> integerList = 
    doubleList.stream()
              .map(l -> l.stream()
                         .map(Double::intValue)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you lack the initialisation of the content. I would do it like this.

```
public List<List<Integer>> convert(List<List<Double>> doubles){
    List<List<Integer>> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<Double> ld: doubles){
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Double d: ld){
            temp.add(d.intValue());
        }
        toReturn.add(temp)
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Basically, for each list in the double list of lists ( not really a matrix, but you could view it as one), you create a list in the integer list of lists and convert the single content.

P.S. this approach is more like Java 7 though, since a pure Java 8 would use streams as suggested in another answer.

Comment: Yep, you are right. But it just draft code written here. It`s not real, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can get rid of the boilerplate code `collect(Collectors.toList())` with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
StreamEx.of(listOfDoubles)
        .map(e -> StreamEx.of(e).map(Double::intValue).toList())
        .toList();
```

To me, the readability and maintainability of above code is much better the cod e with JDK stream API:

```
List<List<Integer>> integerList = 
    doubleList.stream()
          .map(l -> l.stream()
                     .map(Double::intValue)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```